# Look up settings by key/name in Bicep?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I have a list of subnets defined in my *.parameter.json file.

```
"subnetAddressPrefixes": {
    "value": [
        {
            "name": "primary",
            "addressPrefix": "10.2.0.0/17"
        },
        {
            "name": "APIManagementSubnet",
            "addressPrefix": "10.2.246.0/24"
        },
        {
            "name": "ApplicationGatewaySubnet",
            "addressPrefix": "10.2.251.0/24"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to look this up inside my bicep using the name.

To access the value 'primary', I'm using a syntax like this one: `subnetAddressPrefixes[0].name`

I want to be able to look the value up by name using this or any other mechanism in Bicep.

```
subnetAddressPrefixes['primary']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `filter` lambda function to achieve a similar outcome (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-lambda#filter)):

```bicep
var primaryAddressPrefix = filter(subnetAddressPrefixes, x => x.name == 'primary')[0].addressPrefix
```